# How to update mysql records with variables using Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have a local mysql database with some records and I need to create a code to update them using python.
I am new of python language but I already have esperience with others language like php and others.
I am trying this follow approach, where there is my PRIMARY KEY uniquefield that I should use to find and update the right record, using variables

When I try to execute my code an error like "mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not enough parameters for the SQL statement"

Thanks

This is my code:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="",
  database="football"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()


home = "Chelsea"
away = "Machester City"
resultht = "0-0"
resultft = "1-1"
uniquefield = "Chelsea - Manchester City"

sql = """Update matches SET home = %s, away = %s, resultht = %s, resultft = %s, uniquefield = %s  WHERE uniquefield = %s"""
paramtot = (home, away, resultht, resultft, uniquefield)
mycursor.execute(sql, paramtot)

mydb.commit()

print(mycursor.rowcount, "record updated.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're encountering is due to a mismatch between the number of placeholders in your SQL statement and the number of parameters you're providing in the **paramtot** tuple. In your SQL statement, you have 6 placeholders (%s), but you're providing only 5 parameters. The extra %s in your SQL statement is likely causing the error.

To fix this, you should remove the extra %s from your SQL statement since you're using the **uniquefield** both as a value to update and as a filter criterion in the **WHERE** clause.

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="",
  database="football"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

home = "Chelsea"
away = "Manchester City"  # Fixed the typo in the team name
resultht = "0-0"
resultft = "1-1"
uniquefield = "Chelsea - Manchester City"

sql = """UPDATE matches 
         SET home = %s, away = %s, resultht = %s, resultft = %s 
         WHERE uniquefield = %s"""
paramtot = (home, away, resultht, resultft, uniquefield)
mycursor.execute(sql, paramtot)

mydb.commit()

print(mycursor.rowcount, "record updated.")
```

Comment: It's working! Thank you, my error was stupid :)